# Join two tables in mysql output display as null

Tags: mysql, sql

i tried to join two table in MySQL but output display as null.

**Vendor**

```
id vname        contactno    email                 address  status
1  raja         715487240  kobi.ram@hotmail.com   badulla    2
2  janarthan    77722222   jaranthan@gmail.com    Hali-ela   1

purchase

id   vendor_id    date         total     pay    due  payment_type

400     2        2018-10-08    10000    8000    2000     2
401     2        2018-10-12    12000    6000    6000     2
```

sql query

```
select
    v.vname, p.id, p.date, p.total, p.pay, p.due, p.payment_type
from purchase p, vendor v
WHERE p.vendor_id = v.id and date BETWEEN 2018-10-01 and 2018-10-31
```

Comment: You are not joining tables, you are doing cartesian product, which should not be the best choice in your case as I can see.

Comment: @IShubh the query uses the old-style join, when the join criteria is in the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use join and where clause separately and you missed quote in date values

```
    select v.vname,p.id,p.date,p.total,p.pay,p.due,p.payment_type     
    from purchase p inner join vendor v on
    p.vendor_id = v.id  
    where p.date>= '2018-10-01' and  p.date <='2018-10-31'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4704eb/6

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use single quote for date comparison and just say bye to the old fashioned join, changed join in new format as below

```
SELECT v.vname,p.id,p.date,p.total,p.pay,p.due,p.payment_type 
FROM purchase p 
INNER JOIN vendor v ON p.vendor_id = v.id 
AND p.date BETWEEN '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-31'
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/984801/1

Comment: If the missing quotes are the only problem, then this is just a typo question, and you should vote to close rather than answering it.

Comment: Sorry, I will do the same as suggested from the next time, I found few peoples with good reputations also doing the same so I did it but I realize your words. Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem +1.  You could also have compared using inequalities, but not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and all the support.

Comment: Check the datatype of `data` column it must be `DATE` type.

Comment: yes i done it correct date datatype i put as DATE sir but output display as  MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0032 seconds.)

Answer (score 0):

i think its happened due to date time format

please add date format before your query

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
```